# Running Ipython Notebook on Mac

Tags: python, macos, ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Have a question.

I know that Ipython Notebook can be opened by entering `ipython notebook` in terminal on macOS. But is there another option to run it? for example, using some nice app or smth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda, you can use the [anaconda launcher](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-launcher/). If you don't have it, you can install it with:

```
conda install launcher
```

This will install an application called Launcher which will give you a GUI to launch notebooks (and other things).